# Preview and count A4 pages in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

My project output’s user generated content into pdf documents, I would like to create some kind of ‘preview’ in HTML/JS before the document will be converted to PDF.

Is there some way to create a preview which calculates the total number of a4 pages including a clickable pagination?

I could come up with an A4 sized content wrapper and CSS transform scale to fit the content, and add some a4 format negative margin when the user clicks to see the next page. I am wondering what options could be interesting to check for or could be better?

Comment: browser has built in print preview which has pagination and allows to save as pdf etc.

Comment: Not what I am searching for

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand your question. You are creating a project which converts HTML/CSS to a PDF document, but you're not sure how to preview of the PDF before conversion, which includes A4 pagination. Is that right? This is a pretty broad question so it may be better to narrow it down to something more suited to SO, and show that you have attempted the problem, maybe show some code or pseudo code on achieving this goal. As for actually solving it, it will entirely depend on your HTML->PDF convertor. See how the browser to PDF function does it, and what options it has.